Invalid or incomplete assembly store data after repacking AAB
I have problem with my Android app, built with .NET MAUI.
I have a pipeline, in Azure DevOps that should build and deploy the android app.
The deploy steps should update some configuration steps and rebuild the bundle and sign in.
Everything seems to work, I can upload the app to Google Play without any issues.
But when I start the app, it crashes or freezes.
If I go to Google Play console, I find this crash message:
(ensure_valid_assembly_stores): Invalid or incomplete assembly store data

Here are the steps in my pipeline I do after I have changed some settings. I have tried to not do the changes, just repack it with same result. So my conclusion is that it is something with the repacking. I also got the same problem if I run the same command in a terminal local on my machine.
 - task: ArchiveFiles@2
   inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/App/$(PackageId)/base"
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: "zip"
      archiveFile: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/App/base.zip"
      replaceExistingArchive: true

  # Repack aab
    - powershell: |
        cd $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/App/
        java -jar $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/BundleTool/bundletool.jar build-bundle --modules=base.zip --output=$(PackageId).aab
      displayName: Repack aab

     # Resign aab File
    - task: AndroidSigning@3
      displayName: "Sign aab file"
      inputs:
         apkFiles: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/App/$(PackageId).aab"
         apksignerKeystoreFile: "${{ parameters.keystore }}"
         apksignerKeystorePassword: "$(AndroidApkSignerKeystorePassword)"
         apksignerKeystoreAlias: "my-alias"
         apksignerKeyPassword: "$(AndroidApkSignerKeystorePassword)"
         apksignerArguments: "--min-sdk-version 24"

     # Rename the package file
      - powershell: |
           cd $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/App/
           Rename-Item -Path $(PackageId).aab -NewName $(AndroidUploadFilename)
        displayName: Rename the package file

I also tried to add a bundleconfig:
{
   "optimizations": {
      "splits_config": {
         "split_dimension": [
            {
               "value": "ABI",
               "negate": false
            },
            {
               "value": "SCREEN_DENSITY",
               "negate": true
            },
            {
               "value": "LANGUAGE",
               "negate": true
            }
         ]
      },
      "uncompress_native_libraries": {
         "enabled": false
      }
   }
}

Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?
